# non-equi join and aggregation

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to create summary stats for the data shown below using two methods.  In each case I am aggregating the data after the merge and filter.  Looking at some other examples for non equi joins (method 2), it seems like I should be able to aggregate at the same time as the merge and filter.  Can somebody help with that?    Also, it is possible to do without explicitly creating a variable `indDt_3mo`?

```
require(data.table)

#member info
mem.dt <- data.table(data=c(
    "111|2/1/2015","125|3/15/2015","225|4/20/2015","300|5/1/2015"
))
mem.dt[, c("memId","indDt"):=tstrsplit(data, "|", fixed=TRUE)][, data:=NULL]
mem.dt[, ":="(memId=as.integer(memId),indDt=as.Date(indDt, format="%m/%d/%Y"))]

#claims
claims.dt <- data.table(data=c(
"111|var1|1/10/2015","111|var1|12/15/2014","111|var1|8/15/2014","225|var1|9/30/2014","225|var2|10/30/2014"
))
claims.dt[, c("memId","var","servDt"):=tstrsplit(data, "|", fixed=TRUE)][, data:=NULL]
claims.dt[, ":="(memId=as.integer(memId),servDt=as.Date(servDt, format="%m/%d/%Y"))]


#method 1 - filter & agg after merge
mem.dt[claims.dt, on="memId"][indDt-90<=servDt & servDt<=indDt][, 
    .(cnt=uniqueN(servDt)), .(memId,var)]


#method 2 - agg after merge & filter
mem.dt[, indDt_3mo:=indDt-90]
mem.dt[claims.dt, .(memId,var,servDt), on=.(memId, indDt>servDt, indDt_3mo<=servDt), nomatch=0L][,
    .(cnt=uniqueN(servDt)), .(memId,var)]
```

Comment: Fyi, since version 1.9.4, I think, you've been able to use `on=` to merge instead of setting keys.

Comment: I have looked through the other SO questions on non-equi joins and also @Arun's talk on the topic. It hasn't helped me address the above issue.  Is there any other source/doc that I can look at?  Thx.

Comment: I think you're doing it the idiomatic way with method 2, at least until `by=` allows other values than `.EACHI` in a merge https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/733